# My component is being flagged as loaded twice in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, module, primeng

I have an Angular app and I'm using a PrimeNg component for the menu. I've included the component in my shared module file but when I use ng build --prod I get an error saying that the component is part of the declarations of 2 modules.

However the modules that it complains about are the same module, shared module.

Shared Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";



import {CardModule} from 'primeng/card';
import {InputTextModule} from 'primeng/inputtext';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';
import {CheckboxModule} from 'primeng/checkbox';
import { MenubarModule } from "primeng/menubar";
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/accordion';
import {TableModule, Table} from 'primeng/table';
import { DialogModule } from "primeng/dialog";
import {TabViewModule} from 'primeng/tabview';
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { MenuComponent } from '../Logged-In/menu.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations : [MenuComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CardModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ButtonModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MenubarModule,
    AccordionModule,
    TableModule,
    DialogModule,
    TabViewModule,
    DropdownModule
  ],
  exports :[
    CardModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ButtonModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AccordionModule,
    Table,
    DialogModule,
    TabViewModule,
    DropdownModule,
    MenuComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModuleModule { }
```

Error message:

```
ERROR in Type MenuComponent in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/Logged-In/menu.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModuleModule in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/modules/shared-module.module.ts and SharedModuleModule in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/Modules/shared-module.module.ts! Please consider moving MenuComponent in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/Logged-In/menu.component.ts to a higher module that imports SharedModuleModule in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/modules/shared-module.module.ts and SharedModuleModule in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/Modules/shared-module.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes MenuComponent in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/Logged-In/menu.component.ts then import that NgModule in SharedModuleModule in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/modules/shared-module.module.ts and SharedModuleModule in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/Modules/shared-module.module.ts.
Cannot determine the module for class MenuComponent in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/RenasaOnlineClaims/Concourse.ROC.Angular/src/app/logged-in/menu.component.ts! Add MenuComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

I've tried removing it but that then tells me that the component can't be found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you have not imported `MenuComponent` in any other module's declaration array. **VScode** have a feature for global search just hit `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and search `MenuComponent`.

Comment: Have you added the `MenuComponent` into any other module that is also imported in `SharedModuleModule`?

Comment: Also you have a typo in `SharedModuleModule` class name

Comment: I've had a look and the menu component is only declared once and that's in the shared module :(